# Sending Data Array over Serial

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I have a serial port called `COM1` to which I want to synchronously write some data, but when using data with more than one row I get an error:

```
test1 = randi([0,255],1,32);
test2 = randi([0,255],2,32);
fwrite(COM1, test1, 'int8', 'sync'); %successful
fwrite(COM1, test2, 'int8', 'sync'); %unsuccessful
```

The error I get with `test2` simply says `Unsuccessful write: An error occurred during writing.` Is it possible to send data as an array in this way? If so, I suspect the problem lies in how the rows get terminated. How do I ensure the terminators of the arrays and serial port match? I am aware of `set(COM1, 'Terminator', X)` but don't know what `X` should be to match a MATLAB array.

Using MATLAB version 9.3.0.713579 (R2017b).

Comment: What is on the receiving end? Should it behave differently when it receives an array vs. a vector? Can you maybe encode your array somehow (e.g. gzip or even `mat2str(...)`) and decode it on the other side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply a data format requirement for `fwrite/serial`. The data `A` should a vector, not an array. You should try

```
fwrite(COM1, test2(:), 'int8', 'sync');
```

But make sure the column-major order is what you need. Otherwise, you will do

```
test2 = test2.'; % will send in row order
fwrite(COM1, test2(:), 'int8', 'sync');
```